# Wordpress installation in subfolder not working with nginx

Tags: permalinks, nginx

In nginx server the scenario is installing Wordpress in subfolder mydomain.com/new with domain specific nginx configuration (conf.d/mydomain.com.conf) below:

```
server  {
listen 80;
server_name mydomain.com *.mydomain.com;
root    /var/www/mydomain;
index   index.php index.html index.htm;
# error_log  /var/log/nginx/mydomain-error.log warn;

aio threads;
    set_real_ip_from 127.0.0.1;
    set_real_ip_from 10.0.0.0/8;
    real_ip_header X-Real-IP;
    add_header      Via     "1.1 varnish-v4.1";
    gzip_vary       off; # already handled from upstream server

    include includes/cloudflare.conf;
    include includes/fastcgi-wordpress.conf;

location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args /index.php?q=$uri&$args;
    expires 30d;
}

    # Deny access to uploads that aren’t images, videos, music, etc.
    location ~* ^/wp-content/uploads/.*.(html|htm|shtml|php|js|swf)$ {
        deny all;
    }

    # Deny public access to wp-config.php
    location ~* wp-config.php {
        deny all;
    }

    # Deny access to wp-login.php. Do not enable due to admin-ajax.php!! T_T
    # location = /(wp-login|login).php {
    #    limit_req zone=one burst=1 nodelay;
    #    fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
    # }

    location ~ \.php$ {
            try_files $uri /index.php;
            fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
            include fastcgi_params;
            include includes/fastcgi-http.conf;
    }

# location ~ /purge(/.*) {
#     fastcgi_cache_purge WORDPRESS "$scheme$request_method$host$1";
# }  

location ~* ^.+\.(ogg|ogv|svg|svgz|eot|otf|woff|mp4|ttf|css|rss|atom|js|jpg|jpeg|gif|png|ico|zip|tgz|gz|rar|bz2|doc|xls|exe|ppt|tar|mid|midi|wav|bmp|rtf)$ {
    access_log off; 
    log_not_found off;
    expires max;
}

location = /robots.txt {
    access_log off;
    log_not_found off;
}

location ~ /\. {
    deny  all; 
    access_log off;
    log_not_found off;
}

}
```

The mydomain.com is running fine but in mydomain.com/new | all media and permalinks keep redirected to mydomain.com instead of mydomain.com/new.
Which configuration should be modified to fix this? I'm new to this nginx configuration and how to prevent whole server/domain error if configuration failed (there's multi domain in this server)
Many Thanks for the the help.

Answer (score 4):

The problem resolved, I just need to add a location entry as follow:

```
location /new {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /new/index.php?$args /new/index.php?q=$uri&$args;
}
```